# Python 2.7 error when installing package using wheel files

Tags: python, python-wheel, pyhook

I am trying to install pyHook with a wheel file (.whl) but for some reason it keeps giving me this error:

```
 pyHook-1.5.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I got the wheel file from this website:

[http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

The command I use is:

```
pip install pyHook-1.5.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
```

I have no idea what to do, I cant find any suggestions.

- Python version 2.7.6
- Pip version 20.2.3
- Windows x64

Comment: Why aren't you doing `pip install pyhook` to let `pip` decide what version it needs? If you specifically need version `1.5.1` you can do `pip install pyhook==1.5.1`.  Also, are you absolutely sure you have to use Python 2.7.6? it is ancient.

Comment: I used py --version and pip --version: http://prntscr.com/v0rdxc

Comment: I did not question the versions you are using. I questioned *why* you are using these versions

Comment: Oh right.. about the "pip install pyhook==1.5.1" it doesn't work too and i installed the python 3.5: http://prntscr.com/v0t69u

Comment: Hint: You have Windows x64 but 32-bit Python. Either install 32-bit wheel or install 64-bit Python.